# DataTables column search for exact match with regex

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables plugin in my application. I am trying to search for a string that exactly matches the data in a column. I checked jQuery DataTables - Filter column by an exact match which is not working for my case. My search string is a regular expression with | symbols which might look like s1|s2|s12. When the search string contains only s1 at that time s1 record is shown , but when i search multiple values s1|s2 then no records are shown

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                    .columns("#")
                    .search("^"+'s1|s2'+"$",true,false)
                    .draw();
```

Result: No result found .

when i tried below code then addtional  records are shown up

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().search('s1|s2').draw();
```

Result: s1,s2,s11,s14,s22,s25 etc.

Any help would be much appreciated ..

Answer (score 2):

You missed by two brackets.

```
jQuery("#myTable").DataTable()
                    .columns("#")
                    .search('^(s1|s2)$',true,false)
                    .draw();
```

And `search('s1|s2')` did not give desired results because by default regex is disabled in search method. So it is considering `s1|s2` as a string which will match s, 1, 2, |, s1, 1| .. etc. You have to provide second parameter as `true` and third parameter as `false` to avoid conflict and cause unexpected results. See [search() method](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) for more information.